# Can code "run forever" if it contains no loops?

Tags: halting-problem, loops

Is it possible to write a piece of code that will run forever without using a loop?

Comment: A piece of code, in what language?  What constitutes a loop?

Comment: recursion without base case ?

Comment: A concrete machine has a finite number of states.

Comment: How do you define "loop"? E.g. `function run() { return run(); }; run();` will run forever, and it does not contain an explicit looping statement.

Answer (score 2):

As many others have mentioned in the comments, it would depend on what you define as a loop. In any programming language with recursion, it is possible to define a theoretically non-terminating program by doing something like:

```python
def f (x):
   return f(x)

f(5)
```

Which does not contain any explicit loops; (of course this practically does terminate at some point, since the system runs out of memory, but one could argue that it is not possible to define an actual infinite loop, since the computer will not be on forever :) )

On the other hand, if you consider non-well-founded recursion as "a loop", or remove the possibility to write recursive functions - or even all functions - completely, you end up with a language that is only capable to compute only the so called *primitive recursive functions*, i.e. the ones that can be computed without using while loops. With these constraints, **there is no way to define a non-terminating program!**

Note that you could still emulate "true" for loops by copy-pasting your code a bunch of times, since they have a maximum number of iterations; therefore, you don't even need for loops to compute the primitive recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head it's a "no, it can't run forever."

I first imagined some Python code in my head without any loops, and I thought, "it must come to an end"

But then I saw the Halting Problem tag, and I realized this would relate to turing machines, and it would give a more definitive proof as well.

All code can be broken down into a Turing Machine. A literal loop in a Turing Machine would be exactly as you expect it.

[image: Some example Turing Machine]

A Turing Machine is just a directed graph, with arrows telling you which way to move the tape, and which state to go to, based on what the tape says. This directed graph should have some sort of cycle/loop in order to well cycle/loop. So by definition, a Turing Machine cannot cycle let-alone forever, without a cycle existing in the first place. i.e. A well defined turing machine cannot go forever, and must eventually halt if there is no loop present.

That is unless there is an infinite amount of unique states, imagining an infinite chain of nodes, where you start on the left, and are always moving towards to the right to the halt/finish state.

But that would likely be the equivalent to an infinite amount of unique code, which is not possible given that all programming languages have a finite amount of words, and things you're allowed to type. And we might run out of memory first.

Answer (score 0):

Easily with recursion. For example the C function

```
void f() { f (); f (); }
```

will run forever, given arbitrary amounts of memory.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to write a code that would "run forever" without a loop.

A program that runs forever basically means that it always has some statement to execute. In absence of all kinds of loops (while(1), for(;;), recursion, etc.), you will have to write infinite number of statements so that your program can continue running forever.

Another alternative is that you can put a pause like statement in your program and your program will stop at that pause statement but it will not exit. So, your program has not exited but it is also not doing anything. Now, it depends on you whether you consider this as a program running forever.

Comment: You should argue your answer in order to make it clear and, eventually, debatable

Comment: I have modified my answer.